# Unable to add sys.path to python script in Mac OS using relative path (..)

Tags: python, operating-system, filepath, python-module, sys

I am using python 3.9.7 on the latest Mac OS, I am still on an intel Mac. This is what my file directory looks like.

```
home dir (xxx) 
 |
 |---machinelearning
 |        |
 |        |-------scripts
 |                  |-----script1.py
 |
 |---mainscripts
 |        |
 |        |-------misc
 |                  |-----global_variables.py
```

Within my `script1.py` file, I want to include some variables I declared in `global_variables.py`.

So I wrote the following inside `script1.py`,

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '../../mainscripts/misc'))
```

but when I print out sys.path,

I only see this,

```
../../mainscripts/misc
/Users/xxx/machinelearning/scripts
/Users/xxx/miniconda3/envs/xx/lib/python39.zip
/Users/xxx/miniconda3/envs/xx/lib/python3.9
/Users/xxx/miniconda3/envs/xx/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload
/Users/xxx/miniconda3/envs/xx/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

I know I can add the absolute path, but I want to add the relative path, is it possible?

I have also tried using `os.path.join('..','..','mainscripts','misc')` but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried relative imports? [official docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports)

Comment: @Kaz i dont understand how the __init__.py files work, do i have to list all the modules inside ?

Comment: @Kaz it doesnt work, i added __init__.py files in all the paths

Comment: better use absolut path instead of relative path `../..` - when it will run code from different folder then relative path will be relative to different folder then you expect. In many answers you can see how to create absolute path to main `script.py` - `BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` and use it to create absolute path to other elements - modules, images, data files, etc. `full_path = os.path.join(BASE, '..', '..', 'mainscripts', 'misc')`

Comment: `os.path.join('..','..','mainscripts','misc')` doesnt work but youre saying `os.path.join(BASE, '..', '..', 'mainscripts', 'misc')` will? the script isnt registering the `..`, let me give it a try